# Homepod touch interface is now causing homepod to speak its commands - how to turn off?

Tags: homepod

My Homepod (original) has started doing this weird thing where it 'says' the thing when you use the touch controls in a robotic (non Siri) voice.  It says 'play' or 'pause' or 'increase volume' or 'decrease volume'.  I thought maybe it was some accessibility feature but I haven't changed anything and can't find a setting about this.

Comment: Mine doesn't do this, fully updated. I've got a mini and original - certainly a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same thing happened to mine after the latest update.
You can fix it by toggling Voiceover on and off under the Homepod settings in the Home app.